# Unable to display error message in view using ejs templates

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ejs, registration

---

I am new to node.js. I am unable to display error messages in view using ejs templates.I want to display **This user already exists**.Here is my codes :

node.js

```
router.post('/signup', (req, res) => {

    var username = req.body.username;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    let err_msg = '';

    db.query('SELECT * FROM user_data WHERE username = ? and email = ?',  [username,email],(err,rows) => {

        if(err) 
        {
            err_msg = "Some error occured , plz register again.";
            return res.render('signup', { err_msg: err_msg } );
        }

        if (!rows.length)
        {
            db.query('INSERT INTO `user_data`(`username`,`email`,`password`) VAlUES (?, ?, ?)', [username,email,password], (err, results) => {
        return res.redirect('login'); 
        });

        }
        else
        {
            err_msg = "This user already exists.";
            return res.render('signup', { err_msg: err_msg } );
        }
    });
});
```

---

HTML Code

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><%= err_msg %></div>
```

Comment: what's the error you're getting here? besides, in ejs template you are calling `err_msg` as `error_msg` it should give an error.

Comment: Sorry thats err_msg in HTML code , error i get is err_msg not defined...

Comment: well, after changing that mistake, the error should not come again as earlier it was not defined.

Comment: i want to display error messages from the server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if(locals.err_msg) { %>
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><%= err_msg %></div>
<% } %>
```